# How to expand/decrease height of table cell?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Got a Jsfiddle where I have a textarea which fills a table cell. But what I need help with is can somebody create a function in the fiddle where the user expands or decrease the size of the table cell. I want to test my css to see if the textarea can fill the textarea if the table cell height is increased or decreased?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BpWes/1/

Below is the code from fiddle:

HTML:

```
        <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="question">
         <textarea class="textAreaQuestion" id="mainTextarea"  name="questionText"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('textarea').css('background','#EAEAEA');
```

CSS:

```
td{ vertical-align:top}


#tbl{
border:1;
height:250px;    
}

.question{     
    border:1px black solid;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%
}

.textAreaQuestion{
    width:100%;

    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;  

    margin:0;

}
```

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
 <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="question">
<div class="divheight">
    <textarea class="textAreaQuestion" id="mainTextarea"  name="questionText"></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
.question{     

        border:1px black solid;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .divheight{
    height:100%
    }
```

Comment: How do you want the user to increase/decrease the cell height?

Comment: I recognize that css... as I mentioned in prior post...tables don't animate well. Use inner div in TD's and animate those so rows collapse as content does. Don't give cells any height, just inner DIV. Much better looking than animating row... **why the new user name?** Same module, different user

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just want an expand and decrease buttons where when clicked it will increase/decease the cell height of the table. I then want to see if the textarea will automatically increase or not. I want the textarea to increase or descrease with the table cell.

Comment: @charlietfl I am working with somebody and he gave me this fiddle. I just created this account as Im not in SO.

Comment: @charlietfl I included update, is the above what you meant, am in the right direction?

Comment: yup.. then control cell height with `divheight` css. Animating the DIV will be smoother than cell

Comment: @charlietfl I have set up cell height with .divheight haven't I? As I have stated height:100%;

Comment: percentage won't work since you want to use the DIV to control height. If parent ( in this case the cell) has no height `100%` will still be nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BpWes/36/), whether it solves your problem.

```
var cell = $('td.question');

$('.increase').click(function(){
    cell.height(cell.height()+20);
});
$('.decrease').click(function(){
    cell.height(cell.height()-20);
});
```

Comment: Yes this has set up really well, now looking at the way you have done it you have increaed it by 20px each time so the textarea knows to increase by 20px everytime. Same for decrease. Now in the main app, the table could expand or decrease to any size, not a fix size, we won't know how much it will increase or decrease, but I want the textarea to still fit the table cell. Do you know how to change the jquery to something like this?

Comment: @user1941871 I don't think you have to adjust the `textarea height` since you have given it a `100%` height. It will adjust self to the `100%` of the container.

Comment: Ok you see the reason I am asking for this is because I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XM8hG/28/, In the fiddle, click on the "Add Question" button to append a row. Then in appended row click on "Open Grid" and select one option and then the other and you can see under "Question" column that textarea does not fill table cell when expanded or decreased

Comment: @user1941871 I've updated the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XM8hG/30/ . Changes are present in the ` $('.gridBtns').on('click', function(e)` handler

Answer (score 0):

here is an example,I think it helps you

http://jsfiddle.net/BpWes/37/

click on the button,you can see the text area  fills the table cell when we change the height and width.

html

```
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="question">
         <textarea class="textAreaQuestion" id="mainTextarea"  name="questionText"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
<input type ="button" value="expand" id ="expand"/>
```

jquery

```
  $('textarea').css('background','#EAEAEA');

$("#expand").click(function(){    
$(".question").height(500);
$(".question").width(500);
 });
```

Comment: I want an expand and decrease buttons where when clicked it will increase/decease the cell height of the table. I then want to see if the textarea will automatically increase or not. I want the textarea to increase or descrease with the table cell.

Comment: if you are going to give an API reference... at least give the official one  who's docs can be trusted: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Ok similar to now what I said to Arun. In your code I am assuming the textarea knows to expand to 500, but look at the comment I sent to Arun below his answer,

Comment: Ok you see the reason I am asking for this is because I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XM8hG/28/, In the fiddle, click on the "Add Question" button to append a row. Then in appended row click on "Open Grid" and select one option and then the other and you can see under "Question" column that textarea does not fill table cell when expanded or decreased